# Ruby model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have about 12 models but I'm not sure how to make relations and another stuff with 3 model:

Current relationships:

```
purchase has_many purchase_items 

purchase_item belongs_to item

purchase_item belongs_to purchase

item has_many purchase_items
```

I've made working form, where I can create new purchase (add multiple items), but now i want to store in table 'inventory' actual quantity of items, so after create/update/delete model purchase or purchase_items (I'm not sure which) model 'inventory' should be updated also. I know that I have to make this in ActiveRecord callback.

Questions:

- Which relation should I use to make that and between which models?
- Current snippet of code in view (new purchase):

  ```
  <%= purchase_form.nested_fields_for :purchase_items do |nested| %>
  ```

Do I have to add something to this ^ for model inventory?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't necessarily need to update your `inventory` model to accomplish this. Consider solving it like this:

```
# purchase_item.rb
after_save :update_quantity

def update_quantity
  item.quantity --
end
```

And accessing the inventory for each specific item could be something like this:

```
# inventory.rb

def get_inventory_for_item(item)
  item.quantity
end
```

Comment: what "item.quantity --" do ? From what I understand, after save in purchase_item make update_quantity, but I dont have in model 'item' field 'quantity'. In model item, I store only information about product like name, description and etc, with warehouse_id also, because every item is related with some warehouse, so my process for items look like: 1.Add item (item model) 2.Add item to warehouse (purchase model + purchase_items)

Comment: `quantity` was intended to keep track of the amount of a certain `item` you still had in stock, thus decrementing it each time you sell an item (create a purchase_item).

Comment: purchase = increasing items in stock, sell = decreasing, but "--" is some kind of method or what? Because I still don't understand what, and WHERE is updating

Comment: `--` means 'decrease by one' (the opposite of `++`). This would update an attribute on the `item` model (called `quantity`). So in your `update_quantity` method you would either increment (`++`) or decrement ( `--`) based on whether it was a sale or a purchase.